# Merge items in list with one common Number

Tags: python, list

If I have a list like this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0), (0, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (3, 11), (4, 12), (4, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15)]
```

Is there a way to merge the lists with one common number into sth. like (0,1,2),(0,1,7) etc?

I have tried playiing around with:

```
   list_1 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
   list_2 = [3, 4]
   set_1 = set(list_1)
   set_2 = set(list_2)
   list_2_items_not_in_list_1 = list(set_2 - set_1)
   combined_list = list_1 + list_2_items_not_in_list_1
   print(combined_list)
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the given input? Should (1, 2) be merged with (2,3) or with (0, 1) or with both?

Comment: use `for`-loop for this.

Comment: what is expected output for your example list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want check all pairs.

```
from itertools import permutations

lst = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0), (0, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (3, 11), (4, 12), (4, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15)]
res = [(*a, b[1]) for a, b in permutations(lst, r=2) if a[1] == b[0]]
```

If you want check pairs with checking of order into `lst`.

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0), (0, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (3, 11), (4, 12), (4, 13), (5, 14), (5, 15)]
res = [(*a, b[1]) for a, b in combinations(lst, r=2) if a[1] == b[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this now because I am using a python libary function:

```
for x in range(len(res)):
    k=res[x]
    x=k[0]
    y=k[1]
    z=k[2]
    ang=rdMolTransforms.GetAngleDeg(conf, x, y, z)
    allangle=str("%.0f" % ang)
```

My output is now:

```
118
87
148
118
94
154
123
118
118
87
148
118
94
154
118
```

How do i check if the string contains the number 118? and print how often it appears in my results.